# Anyone can help me for example SSH Code for Android?

Tags: android

I want to create android application for SSH to Linux Server.
But I can't find a topic with SSH connect to server
anyone can help me for SSH Source code to connect SSH Server.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can look at jsch which is Java ssh client library. http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

However, there are some really good ssh clients out there already (ConnectBot), so may be you can build something else?

Comment: I want to create applicationsend eg. button1 send command to restart server. button2 send command to restart ssh service

Comment: I think, jsch should allow you to create a tunnel and run command over it. But I never tried it.